# javascript regex exclude dot

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm finding difficulties making the right regex. I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

pattern:

```
href=".*?\/FileBrowser\/File\?path=esoft\/[^.\s]*?"
```

test string:

```
dfhgndfhkljh;fth href="/FileBrowser/File?path=esoft/test/I4/I0000/as.jpeg" dfghfdhnjfgh e:small;"><a href="/FileBrowser/File?path=esoft/test/bb/2evo/1_folder" target="_blank"dsadsadsa
```

and the site I use to test online is https://regex101.com/r/mU5vH6/2

The goal is to mark the links (after the href) separately as shown https://regex101.com/r/mU5vH6/3 here, but if one of them has a dot - meaning file path, not to be included

Comment: yes, a downvote without an explanation is a good way of being helpful.... to the community. I know there is a question how to exclude dot from regex, but I cannot make it work

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/hD2pW4/1)?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but I am sitting here still wondering what on earth you are asking.   The last sentence in your question in particular makes no sense to me.  What is the "them" that this sentence refers to?

Comment: @Thomas yes, exactly.. give it as an answer so I could accept it

Comment: @GreenAsJade them is refering to the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
href="[^"]*\/FileBrowser\/File\?path=esoft([^.])*?"
```

The previous one was matching:

```
dfhgndfhkljh;fth href="/FileBrowser/File?path=esoft/test/I4/I0000/as.jpeg" dfghfdhnjfgh e:small;"><a href="/FileBrowser/File?path=esoft/test/bb/2evo/1_folder" target="_blank"dsadsadsa
                 |___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________|
```

Because you allowed your match to contain `"`, which consumed too much chars